# Resizable Jquery Boundary

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

Hello I am setting resizable and draggable boundaries by using **ui.position.left** which seems to work perfectly with draggable. However the problem is that resizable also stops but the width continues expanding. Is there anyway to stop that from happening? Thanks so much.

EDIT:  I can't rely on "containment" because the boundaries are actually other elements within the container.

Comment: Could you provide us with a code snippet of your try?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by storing the ui.size.width each resize and once the boundary is hit I set the width to the previous width.

EDIT: thanks for anyone who looked at my question